# Matching data with Lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I'm attempting to try and match a term to a list of products in my database. Let's start lucene with some simple data:

```
//Table Products
Glue
Glue Sticks
Crayons
Markers
```

Here's the tricky part: I'm attempting to match the best result but there may be junk data involved (Later in the string). Let me give you an example:

If I search for `Glue Sticks are the best type of Grapefruit`, I'd like it to match `Glue Sticks`. Right now, it's matching `Glue` as my top result. Here is my code:

Indexing:

```
using (
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.Open("index"), new CaseInsensitiveKeywordAnalyzer(),
                                            true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED))
{
    foreach (var product in DB.Products.OrderBy(c => c.Id).AsEnumerable())
    {
        var doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("Id", product.Id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        doc.Add(new Field("Name", product.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,
                                Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
        writer.AddDocument(doc);
    }
    writer.Optimize();
    writer.Commit();
}
```

The Search:

```
var qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Name", new SimpleAnalyzer());
var q = qp.Parse(productName);
var hits = searcher.Search(q, 10);
```

Does anyone recommend a different analyzer I can use, or a better way to handle this search? Ideally, I'd like it to boost terms closer toward the start, as the junk will always follow the product I'm looking for (Never before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `SimpleAnalyzer` when you index your documents, as well as when you search.  It's usually a good idea to keep analysis at index and query time the same until you have a good reason to do otherwise.

```
using (
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.Open("index"), new SimpleAnalyzer(),
                                        true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED))
```

With your Keyword analyzer, you had a single term in the field:  `glue sticks`.  Then your simpleAnalyzed query has the following terms:

`glue`, `sticks`, `are`, `the`, `best`, `type`, `of`, and `grapefruit`.

None of which are actually a match on the single term: `glue sticks`.